# Change Panel Font Weight

Tags: 16.04, themes, customization

I want to change font weight of:

1. unity panel:

[Unity Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGB8j.png)

2. Window Menu bar and nautilus current folder label:

[Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKJMJ.jpg)

to the **font-weight: normal**;

as you can see i already set unity tweak tool settings to the:

Default font: Ubuntu Regular 10

Document font: Ubuntu Regular 10

Window Title font: Ubuntu medium 10

But i just want the font-weight of those that i mentioned be normal and not regular.

I'm using ARC theme and i know i can change it by this file

```
/usr/share/themes/Arc/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
```

but i don't know which class is belonging to them.